# Relationship query in SQL repeat records

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm trying to link two tables in SQL but it does not do what I want.
I have a table1 with two fields id, Total and other Table2 that contains 20 fields which I want to extract only 5 ID, Name, Address, City, Province. The query I have is as follows:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table2.name, Table2.address, Table2.city, Table2.province, Table1.Total
  FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON
 WHERE Table2.id Table1.Total Table1.id => = "& CLng (number1.Text ) &
  "AND Table1.Total <=" & CLng (number2.Text) &
"ORDER BY ASC Table2.name"
```

The intention is to relate the two tables but the problem is that the resulting query has repeated results. I think that the reason is, for example, I have some data with the same id but with different names and it tries to put the different data in different rows in spite of having the same id.

I have spent a lot of time searching a solution but I can't find it.

Comment: Your SQL syntax is not yet correct.  You seem to have partially extracted the SQL from the string you're building in VB6, but you haven't done that completely.  As it stands, the ON clause has no join condition; the WHERE clause has a malformed first term, and the residue is suffering from problems with quotes etc.

Comment: If you are saying that the query returns 20 records but you only want 5, that's known as a top n query.  The way to achieve this depends on the db type and you didn't specify yours.  Also, on StackOverflow, add 4 spaces to the start of each line of code.  That will make it show up as code and make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have your `ON` clause specified properly. Try removing the word `WHERE` so that you actually restrict your join to the relevant rows, rather than doing a full join.

Answer (score 0):

USE Left outer JOIN instead of INNNER JOIN

Check the sql. may be you are expecting like below.

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table2.name, Table2.address, Table2.city, Table2.province, Table1.Total 
FROM    Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table2.id =Table1.id 

WHERE Table1.Total = '' AND Table1.Total <= ''
ORDER   BY  Table2.name ASC
```

Comment: LOJ is not the universal solution to join problems; it certainly isn't likely to be the solution to this problem.  Use LOJ only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table2.name, Table2.address, Table2.city, Table2.province, Table1.Total
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON
Table2.id = Table1.id  WHERE Table1.Total >=  CLng(number1.Text) AND Table1.Total <= CLng(number2.Text)  
GROUP BY Table2.name 
ORDER BY ASC Table2.name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "DISTINCT" statement to return only distinct (different) values. Duplicate rows are returned only once.

Your sql query syntax is wrong. Maybe It returns duplicate rows because that.
But  if after fix it, still returns duplicate rows, Table2 must have multiple rows with the same id. In that case, you can use DISTINCT statement.

The correct SQL Query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.id, Table2.name, Table2.address, Table2.city, Table2.province, Table1.Total
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.id = Table2.id 
     AND Table1.total BETWEEN minValue AND maxValue 
ORDER BY ASC Table2.name
```

(minValue and maxValue are numbers)

in VB syntax

```
" SELECT Table1.id, Table2.name, Table2.address, Table2.city, Table2.province, Table1.Total " _
" FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.id = Table2.id " & _
"      AND Table1.total BETWEEN " & CLng (number1.Text ) &  "AND " & CLng (number2.Text) & _ 
"ORDER BY ASC Table2.name "
```